# I grabbing thousands of tvshow links [a-z] using curl concept

Tags: php

While i am running the curl data values are grabbed but not completely, it is getting an error
as below.

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\includes\simple_html_dom.php on line 70

**I tried this but no use.I want to increase the maximum execution time** 
ini_set("memory_limit","34M");

If any one help this will be appreciated.

Comment: You ran out of time, not memory ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php
what you're looking for is `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: Depending on your hosting service, there may be an upper limit to that setting.

Comment: Of course, but if that's fixed to 30 seconds the only other option in executing a new process, and I really doubt that's allowed :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to write your PHP as a stand-alone program.  Many hosting services would allow you to run it as a `cron` job, which wouldn't have the limits of a script run by the web server.